# How to make one request once an hour, another once every 24 hours

Tags: python, discord

How can I make a script that runs non-stop and have one request every hour and another once every 24h.

```
def main():
    while True:
        requests.post(url, headers = auth, data = msg_work)
        requests.post(url, headers = auth, data = msg_daily)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I need a msg_work request once an hour and a msg_daily request once every 24 hours. I thought about doing it through time.sleep() but I haven't figured out how to do it.

Comment: You can create 2 python scripts and use something like `crontab` or any other scheduler to control the jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
def main():
    hours_passed = 0
    while True:
        requests.post(url, headers = auth, data = msg_work)
        time.sleep(3600)  # it will sleep for a hour
        hours_passed = (hours_passed + 1) % 24
        if hours_passed == 0:  # a day has passed
            requests.post(url, headers = auth, data = msg_daily)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```